# Setting input property of elementRef through directive in angular

Tags: angular

I have a directive which would be applied to element that has an input property named 'icon'. I want to change the value of input property from my directive.

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrolling]'
})

export class ScrollingDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer2, public el: ElementRef, private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit(){this.el.nativeElement.icon= 'someValue'; this.cdr.detectChanges()}
}
```

Html:

```
<my-component scrolling [icon]='some other value'></my-component>
```

The input is of app-component's input. It's not directive's own input. I want to change this value

What I tried?

```
@HostBinding('attr.icon') icon= 'someValue' // Did not work

this.elementRef.nativeElement.icon = 'someValue' // Did not work

this.renderer2.setProperty(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'icon', 'someValue'); // Did not work
```

I am not sure, if it's even possible or not

Answer (score 0):

You can change your icon properties by adding @Input() into your directive, follow my below code

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrolling]'
})
export class ScrollingDirective implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() icon: string; // assign same name that you would like to change

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer2, public el: ElementRef, private cdr: ChangeDetectionRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.icon = 'someValue'; // Set the value of the input property
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Hope it solves your promblem

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Okay @MoannaTabala, Share your stack blitz link if you can